How to Dynamically Create Subdomains for Tenants in a Next.js App Hosted on AWS Amplify?
I am developing a multi-tenant app and want to provide custom subdomain URLs to my users. In the AWS Amplify console, I have configured a domain and need a way to manage subdomains dynamically for each tenant when they register within my app. Specifically, I am looking for a solution to create <tenant.domain> URLs for my Next.js app hosted on AWS Amplify.

To dynamically manage subdomains for each tenant in your multi-tenant app hosted on AWS Amplify with a Next.js front-end, you can leverage AWS Route 53 for DNS management, AWS Lambda for dynamic creation of subdomains, and AWS Amplify's hosting features. Here’s a step-by-step approach:
Step 1: Set Up Your Domain in Route 53
Step 2: Configure Amplify to Use Your Custom Domain (go to your app and add your custom domain e.g. domain.com)
step 3: Create a Lambda Function for Subdomain Creation
Example Lambda function (Python):
import boto3
import os

route53 = boto3.client('route53')

def create_subdomain(event, context):
    domain_name = os.environ['DOMAIN_NAME']
    hosted_zone_id = os.environ['HOSTED_ZONE_ID']
    
    tenant_name = event['tenant_name']
    subdomain = f"{tenant_name}.{domain_name}"

    response = route53.change_resource_record_sets(
        HostedZoneId=hosted_zone_id,
        ChangeBatch={
            'Changes': [
                {
                    'Action': 'UPSERT',
                    'ResourceRecordSet': {
                        'Name': subdomain,
                        'Type': 'A',
                        'AliasTarget': {
                            'HostedZoneId': 'AMPLIFY_APP_HOSTED_ZONE_ID',  # Get this from Amplify console
                            'DNSName': 'AMPLIFY_APP_URL',  # Get this from Amplify console
                            'EvaluateTargetHealth': False
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    )

    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': f"Subdomain {subdomain} created successfully"
    }

Step 4: Trigger Lambda on Tenant Registration (from your application backend to trigger the Lambda function when a new tenant registers)
Step 5: Handle Subdomains in Next.js (configure your routing logic to handle subdomains.)
Example
module.exports = {
  async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/:path*',
        has: [{ type: 'host', value: '(?<tenant>.*).domain.com' }],
        destination: '/:path*'
      }
    ]
  }
}

Step 6: Update Amplify Build Settings
